# Visual Studio Code not signed? Can't run on macOS Catalina

Tags: visual-studio-code, osx-gatekeeper

Downloaded VSCode-darwin-stable.zip from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=osx

Unzipped.  Can't run.

From terminal:
% open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app 
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app.

From Finder:
The application "Visual Studio Code.app" can't be opened.

When I run xattr:
% xattr /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron 
com.apple.quarantine

This is... umm... how did this get released?